# How do you find the count when iterating multiple children in a CakePHP form?

Tags: cakephp

`Student` has many to many a `Course`, and in `View/Students/Edit.ctp` I have the following form which renders a separate course drop down for each existing course taken by the current student. How can I access the applicable count for my iterator limit?

```
<?php 
  echo $this->Form->create('Student');
  for($i = 0; $i < $whats_the_count; $i++) {
   echo $this->Form->input('StudentCourse.' . $i . '.course_id');
  }
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The completely undocumented method `$this->Form->value()` returns an array of IDs for the given field so you can simply use `count($this->Form->value($fieldName))`, i.e.

```
<?php 
  echo $this->Form->create('Student');
  for($i = 0; $i < count($this->form->value('StudentCourse')); $i++) {
    echo $this->Form->input('StudentCourse.' . $i . '.course_id');
  }
?>
```

Answer (score -1):

Can you not simply do something like:

```
$numCourses = count($student->StudentCourse);
```

Comment: No, $student is undefined.

Comment: I guessed, because you gave us no information to go no. Obviously you need some DB info if you want a count.  Might need to rework your entire question.

Answer (score -1):

You need a third table for their connection if they're many to many.
But first of all try to get used to naming things appropriately just so you wont get confused.

example.

Student = 1 student

Students = 2 or more studentS

Course = 1 course

Courses = 2 or more coursES

so to answer the question. You should have a table called students_courses which will connect the two tables using many to many relationship. So that when you query Student(just one) and if you write Student->courses it will give you the courses for that student.

A simple step by step is...
1. Find the one student example JOHN.

```
$student = $this->Students->find()
->contain('Courses')
->where(['name' => 'JOHN'])
->first();
```

2. Pass `$student` to the `edit.ctp` view
3. If you still need to count the courses just write `count($student->courses)` which should work now if you do the previous steps.

An easier way of doing it is finding the `Courses` itself and use `->find('list')` which will give you dropdown options automatically formatted for you. You could read it in the book. Just google cakephp find list.
Hopefully this helps! good luck